# What is the reason behind the Runtime Error "imageio.mimread() has read over 256 MiB of"?

Tags: python, runtime-error

I started getting into coding 40 days ago and last week I realised that using python I can create a first order motion model video which I was amazed by.

Now I already made some using that code flawlessly but now once again, when I reach the "load driving video and source image" cell I get the same error that I got when making other projects being the one in the title.

I don't know if the problem is caused by the size of my driving video because in the first few successful uses I had with this code the dr. video was at around 7,5 MBs while now it's 3,2MBs and apparently it can't be processed. Is there a way to bypass the memtest?

Comment: I recommend you go through the intro tour again. This isn't really a question that can be answered without a lot more info.

Comment: Specifically the code in question. Try and create an MCVE!

Comment: MCVE as in [mre].

Comment: Is the full error "RuntimeError: imageio.mimread() has read over 256 MiB of image data. Stopped to avoid memory problems. Use imageio.get_reader() or memtest=False"?

Comment: Indeed. I was going to add everything to my original report but even there I ran into errors because the code that was attached hadn't been properly indented even though I copied it perfectly from my attempt at making the code work

Comment: Jordan: If you used tabs or a mixture of tabs and space characters to indent your code, then you may have problems adding it to your question. If possible, convert all the tab character to the equivalent space characters and try it again.